# PHP $post and forms

Tags: php

I have a form that has two field inputs that also have the same name "name"

I was wondering what do I have to do , to capture both fields in array,

for example,  if field1 get post and field2 was empty, I would like to get an array[0]
with the data I was looking for and if field1 and field2 where submited, I would like to have array[0] and array[1] populated.

currently the form I have will only capture if both fields are populated and if one of them is populated it wonn't capture .

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<?php 

$name=$_POST['name'];


if($name)
{

    echo $name;

    }


?>


</head>

<body>


<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">

  <p>name
  <input name="name" id="name" type="text" />



  </p>
  Name

  <input name="name"  id="name" type="text" />
  <p>&nbsp;</p>


  <input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like the end results for the variable name to be an array that would have both data that was capture from field one and field two.

thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just use different field names? Although many browsers support multiple fields having the same name being passed as a list/array (when appended with `[]`s), it's not an official specification and should be avoided unless there's a good reason

Comment: There's nothing that says you cannot do this, and I don't know of browsers that don't support it. The `[]` notation is a PHP addition and shouldn't be needed in the first place.

Comment: @Basic I have to use the same name cause the field will be a dynamic java script field. for example, if the user want to add another name, they can then click an add button and a new field will show. thanks

Comment: you could use js to alter the created form inputs to increment the name to name_1 then the next one name_2, but [] is probably going to be easier

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the name of each field to `name[]`, then they can be accessed in PHP using `$_POST['name'][0]` and `$_POST['name'][1]`.

EDIT: You can also use `name[1]` in your HTML to explicitly set indices, or even `name[foo]`, then access from PHP using `$_POST['name']['foo']`.

Comment: Basically, the `[]` in the name turns `$_POST['name']` into an array. :-)

Comment: Unfortunate that this is needed. It would be perfectly valid to name them just `name` and still treat them as an array, but PHP hasn't got built in functionality to support that, so adding the brackets is the easiest solution indeed. Edit: I'd add another +1 for the addition about indices, but alas, I cannot.

Comment: @GolezTrol - aha, just checked and it does. I assume PHP overwrites by default, since in normal mode, it would have to check the POST data twice and either assign to an array or a field, depending on the number of definitions of each name.

Comment: @KhanqueredPro - if it has been useful, please mark it as answered, thanks :)